# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str (Rotten Tomatoes)

Tags: python, string, sdk, int, typeerror

I'm using the Rotten Tomatoes SDK on Python and i'm trying to get a list of all the movies that i'm searching for, but when I do the request, i can only show one result (because: movie[0]['title']), how can I get all the movies as a result?

Here's my code:

```
from rottentomatoes import RT
RT_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXX'
rt = RT(RT_KEY)
movie = raw_input('Enter the movie name: ')
fl = rt.search(movie, page_limit= 5)
title = fl['title'] #In order to work properly and show one result I should use fl[0]['title']
print title
```

but when I run the program, give me that "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" error on the 'title=' line. How can I show all the results? (In strings) Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fl` seems to be a list of movie dicts and you want to get the 'title' key for every dict in `fl`. So instead of `title = fl['title']`, try:

```
title = []
for movie in fl:
    title.append(movie['title'])
```

Comment: but how can I get the movies' titles in strings? when I do what you say, I get 'None'.

Comment: I'm not actually using the RT api, just going from what you posted. If you say `fl[0]['title']` gives you the first title you want (and I suspect then `fl[1]['title']` will give the second), then the code I provided should work. What exactly is not working? (What is `None`)?

Comment: if I use your code, and I store `title.append(movie["title"])` in a variable, and print it, it returns "None"

Comment: Don't worry, I used a Try to fetch 4 possible titles, thanks anyway!